# Laravel Queued Job doesn't wait for exec to coplete

Tags: php, laravel, queue, exec, jobs

i have my queues set up and working (the jobs get run), however the script doesn't seem to wait for my exec line to run before progressing with the next line of code.

This means i'm getting exceptions in the next few lines (because it's looking for a file that hasn't been produced yet)

My closure is:

```
Queue::push(function($job) use ($gid,$eid)
        {
            $phantomLoc = base_path()."/vendor/bin/phantomjs";
            $scriptLoc = app_path()."/libraries/makeVideo.js";
            $pageAddress = route('image_maker_video', array($gid,$eid));
            $imageName = base_path().'/../data/team_images/'.$gid.'/video-sheets/'.$eid."/";
            $execString = $phantomLoc.' '.$scriptLoc.' '.$pageAddress.' '.$imageName;
            //empty the folder first
            Helpers::emptyFolder($imageName);
            exec($execString, $return_array, $return_value);
            if ($return_value == 0) {
                //now convert image sequence to video
                $outputPath = base_path().'/../data/team_images/'.$gid.'/video-sheets/'.$eid;
                $return_value = Helpers::PNGsToVideo($imageName, $outputPath);
                if ($return_value == 0) {
                    //it worked!!
                    Helpers::emptyFolder($imageName);
                    //rmdir($imageName); 
                    return "video in progress";
                    return Redirect::to('/team_images/'.$gid.'/video-sheets/'.$eid.".mkv");
                } else {
                    Log::error($return_value." - ffmpeg return val");
                    abort(500, $return_value." - ffmpeg return val");
                }
            } else {
                Log::error($return_value." - video phantom return val");
                abort(500, $return_value." - video phantom return val");
            }
            $job->delete();
        });
```

and it seems to skip straight through the `exec` line, although i do think it is still being run.

Note, if i change the driver back to `sync` then it all runs completely fine (but obviously not in a queue)

Any idea how to wait for `exec`?

Comment: What do you mean *next step*? Does that mean next queued job? Or next line of code?

Comment: next line of code, goes straight into the if statment

Comment: question edited and updated accordingly, thanks!

Comment: Have you dumped out the exec command just to check its not finishing instantly due to an error?

Comment: Just taking apart now, but strange that it returns with 0. Would've thought an error would have given me another code?

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that `exec` was erroring out, but the error (from phatomjs)gave a return code of 0.

Turns out that the error was because the line

```
$pageAddress = route('image_maker_video', array($gid,$eid));
```

Was providing a url that just had `localhost` rather than `localhost:8888`

So i've hacked it to do a string replace for localhost.

Not sure why putting it into a queue would cause laravel to provide incorrect urls. But at least it's working!

Comment: The routes Laravel generates from Queues are based on what you tell it in the .env file. The `APP_URL` setting is what controls this. In the example of the above it should be set to `APP_URL=http://localhost:8888/` in order to generate the correct URLs for your routes. The same goes for Mail::queue and other such commands (as $request, request() and Request() are unavailable through CLI).