# Laravel exec() in queue'd job

Tags: java, php, laravel, redis, queue

I'm using a redis queue with my laravel app. It doesn't appear that calling `exec('{run some java program}')` from within my queue'd job actually executes that command.

Anyone know anything about this?

Answer (score 1):

If there's an error with your external executable for whatever reason, PHP will skip past and ignore the output of exec (you may wish to debug / dump the result of exec() to a file / console to find out more) and therefore so will the queue.

Handy to remember, the PHP-CLI that Queues run in don't have access to anything you'd usually use in a non-CLI (PHP-FPM, Apache module etc...) environment (Request, request() and $request will not work as you expect them to )

Related:

[Laravel Queued Job doesn't wait for exec to coplete](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32460886/laravel-queued-job-doesnt-wait-for-exec-to-coplete)

Comment: Thanks @JustinOBB ! Because of the caveats, any suggestions for alternatives?

Comment: Try these: 1) Grab the output of a synchronous run from command line: `php -r "echo exec('java javaprogram');"` 2) Try using shell_exec() instead of exec() http://php.net/manual/en/function.shell-exec.php 3) Dump output from your java program to see if it ran and has the expected output.